# How do I turn off battery charging in Ubuntu?

Tags: dell, power-management, battery

I mainly work on AC power. Therefore Windows has the below utility to improve battery life for my scenario by disabling battery charging:

[image]

How do I achieve this in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218148/stop-start-battery-charging-through-software and http://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity (specifically: http://askubuntu.com/a/22272/15811 ) and what is stopping you from actually taking out the battery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to charge the battery till 60-80% only?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22268/how-to-charge-the-battery-till-60-80-only)

Comment: @Rinzwind This is asking how to *not* charge the batter at all.. different questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to do this in Ubuntu.
This option is specific for your laptop. Try to find appropriate software for Linux on manufacturer's site.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your BIOS/UEFI.

After turning on, press "F2" until it writes "Preparing to enter setup".

Then, you have to look for the power settings, or something similar.

Within this menu, you can change the settings like you want. I am running a precision M4800 with Ubunt 15.04, and the settings work.