# How can I stop charging my battery at 60%?

Tags: power-management, battery

I have Asus Zenbook UX430UN and in windows it have some kind of battery health management program. And this program propose option called "Maximum Life-span" the idea is to hold battery on +- 60% of charge when in connected to the AC. So, how can I achieve similar result on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [TLP – Linux Advanced Power Management](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html)
>       TLP brings you the benefits of advanced power management for Linux without the need to understand every technical detail. TLP comes with
>   a default configuration already optimized for battery life, so you may
>   just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to
>   fulfil your specific requirements.

Taken from this topic
[How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)
but here you can found about ThinkPad laptops too
Ubuntu package can found here:
[Ubuntu Package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tlp&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all)

Comment: Thx for answer, but I saw this post and my question is, will this work for Asus? Or if vendor already did some software for windows that do this, so laptop have hardware support for this feature and this TLP package could do the trick too?

Comment: Charge thresholds are for ThinkPads only (because of necessary kernel support).

Answer (score 16):

Kernel 5.4 did bring the ability to set the battery percentage under which charging will trigger.

The change in [asus-wmi](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/asus-wmi.c) added a `charge_control_end_threshold` in sysfs.

You can manually set the `charge_control_end_threshold` to 60 in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold` as su to test if it works on your laptop. You should unplug your device and let the battery discharge a little  and then plug your device, if  system doesn't charge your battery when it's over 60% then you're good. but it will regenerate every time you reboot.

A simple udev rule can be made:

```
KERNEL=="BAT0", SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{charge_control_end_threshold}="80"
```

Within `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

Read the [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#udev_rule_example) and [Asus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop/ASUS) articles on Arch wiki for more info.

Comment: I confirm this works on an Asus Zenbook 15 UX534FAC from October 2019 using `clonezilla-live-20200414-focal-amd64` and `archlinux-2020.04.01-x86_64.iso`: first battery was charging at 74% (checked with `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`), then I entered `echo 60 | sudo tee /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold`) and the charging stopped, as confirmed by `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`. Nice!

Comment: This also worked on an ASUS Vivobook X507UF from August 2018 with [Linux kernel v5.5.19](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5.19/) on Ubuntu 19.10 with BIOS version 304.

Comment: You can see this [issue](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/321), more specifically [this comment](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/321#issuecomment-581012796) and [my gist](https://gist.github.com/mhdzli/069e0eac76327b0dfe48e0856deb0a58) based on that. If you want to help the TLP team for supporting more devices.

Comment: this works on my M509D Asus notebook but you mean it resets to 100 each reboot unless I set the rule?

Comment: Lenovo Ideapad does not have this file and trying to create it with 'sudo` says permission denied.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [command line application](https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat) that does this.

The easiest way to get started is download the app from the [releases page](https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat/releases/) and run

```
$ ./bat --help
```

from the terminal in the directory where it is located which should show the help documentation.

If there's an error, it might have to do with permissions. The following command might solve the problem.

```
chmod +x ./bat
```

Basically, running

```
$ ./bat --threshold
```

will print out the current threshold.

To set a new threshold, say 60%, run

```
./bat --threshold 60
```

To persist the current threshold between restarts, run

```
sudo ./bat --persist
```

Note: Persisting uses [systemd](https://systemd.io/) under the hood but this is bundled with most Linux distributions including Ubuntu.

Tip: Putting the app in a directory like `/usr/local/bin/` that is in the `$PATH` will enable you to run it from anywhere and not just in the directory the app is in. Then the above commands become,

```
bat --help
```

```
bat --threshold 60
```

```
bat --persist
```

respectively.