# Asus battery health charging working on Ubuntu 19.10, but not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, power-management, asus, battery, bios

I had **Windows 10** and **Ubuntu 19.10** dual boot on my Asus laptop.

There is a Windows application for this Asus laptop which one can use to change some settings so that the battery does not charge over 60% when the charger is plugged in ([ASUS Battery Health Charging](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1032726/)).

I had found a way to make these settings work in Ubuntu as well:
First I booted into Windows and ran the Asus software. Then I restarted the laptop and booted into Ubuntu 19.10. The settings that I applied it on my Windows also worked on Ubuntu and didn't allow the battery to charge more than **60%**.

But when I upgraded my Ubuntu to version **20.04**, that doesn't happen anymore.

Is it because of the new version of GRUB that overrides the Asus app setting set in Windows?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Related: [How can I stop charging my battery at 60%?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056198/480481)

Comment: I wrote a [command line application](https://github.com/leveson/bat) that does this. (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1311691/527764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your `/etc/crontab`:

```
@reboot root echo 60 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold
```

This works perfectly for me.