# Directories are looping when I boot from my old SSD Ubuntu via USB connection

Tags: lenovo, battery, tlp

I wanted to set charging thresholds on my Ideapad which does not have the tight integration with TLP that my old Thinkpad, from which I took the SSD to connect to my Ideapad, so I looked here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1211506/806813

But my directories don't have that `charge_control_end_threshold` file and they seem to be looping per below.

```
base) nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/device/power_supply/BAT0/device/power_supply/BAT0$ ls
alarm           energy_full_design  power_now      type
capacity        energy_now          present        uevent
capacity_level  hwmon1              serial_number  voltage_min_design
cycle_count     manufacturer        status         voltage_now
device          model_name          subsystem
energy_full     power               technology
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `/sys/class/power_supply` is best considered API interfaces, not files. These can be different on every computer (even if they're the same model) depending on:

- BIOS settings
- battery firmware
- hardware capabilities
- hardware age
- GRUB settings
- etc. ...

Looking at the options that you have in your `BAT0`, you will not be able to set thresholds at this time. What I suggest is that you take a look in your BIOS under the "Power" options for something that will allow you to change the power profile.

Comment: I went into Windows 10 that was included, used the Lenovo Vantage tool to start up battery conservation mode and it seems to be conserving even when I log into Ubuntu on my external SSD.