# Battery switches between charging/not charging

Tags: drivers, asus, battery

I have an ASUS Zenbook Pro 15 and have a problem that I've been dealing with since I bought the laptop. The battery seems to switch between charging/not charging every 10 seconds. This only happens on Linux (Ubuntu Budgie). It's a minor issue, but it's an annoyance when my battery is low because every 10 seconds a low battery warning pops up.

My assumption is that is has something to do with ASUS' battery life software. On Windows there is some preinstalled software by ASUS that allows you to set a maximum battery level. Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?

Comment: @Nmath No. In Windows it works fine. I was just saying that ASUS has software included to set the maximum battery level to prolong the battery's lifespan. I'm wondering if there is some type of firmware that allows that software to work, which causes the issue in Linux.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question here. They also had a ZenBook and the answer was accepted by the asker. See if this works for you: https://askubuntu.com/q/1056198

Comment: @Nmath That question does cover setting a maximum battery level, but I'm not worried about the level. I just want the OS to recognize that the battery is continually charging. For the first 10-20% of battery, I see the low battery popup repeatedly.

Comment: The same is happening to me in a Samsung np700z. So it's not zenbook related...